# JFreeChart changes size when y axis displays negative numbers

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am writing an app that uses JFreeChart, and  the charts update dynamically as the application runs. The JFreeChart is within a ChartPanel, and they are simple XYLineCharts.

Sometimes, the y axis range on the chart can change from positive to negative numbers - in this situation the chart reduces in size to make room for the "-" symbol.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening ?

Thanks

Comment: How is this unexpected? Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem as you see it.

Comment: I didn't say it was unexpected ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `plot.getRangeAxis().setLowerBound(0);`

Comment: As important as the solution is providing details to what this code is doing and why this code would help.

Comment: It will set minimum displayed value of Y axis to 0.